# Conversion of string to empty value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I apologize if this is a possible duplicate. I have a column named 'output' with some of the values like this:

```
{'output': ['{\'err\': True, \'e\': {\'killed\': False, \'code\': 102, \'signal\': None, \'cmd\': \'oasdiff -check-breaking -base  specs/300432.json -revision specs/300430.json -exclude-examples\', \'stdout\': \'\', \'stderr\': \'failed to load base spec from "specs/300432.json" with error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field TBis.components of type string\\n\'}}', '{\'err\': True, \'e\': {\'killed\': False, \'code\': 102, \'signal\': None, \'cmd\': \'oasdiff -check-breaking -base  specs/219996.json -revision specs/219995.json -exclude-examples\', \'stdout\': \'\', \'stderr\': \'failed to load base spec from "specs/219996.json" with error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field TBis.paths of type []string\\n\'}}', "{'err': True, 'e': {'killed': False, 'code': 104, 'signal': None, 'cmd': 'oasdiff -check-breaking -base  specs/819816.json -revision specs/819812.json -exclude-examples', 'stdout': '', 'stderr': 'diff failed with duplicate endpoint (GET /v1/invoices/{pending_only}) found in specs/819816.json and specs/819816.json. You may add the x-since-date extension to specify order\\n'}}"]}
```

The internal content keeps changing but the string always starts with `{'err': True,'e'`, is there a way I can replace all such strings with "" for the whole dataframe?

I tried doing this:

```
df.loc[df['output'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict) and x.get('err') == True and x.get('e') == ''), 'output'] = ''
```

My expected out is this:

```
output
Nan
Nan
Nan
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: I still do not understand what you want to accomplish with `x.get('e') == ''`.

Comment: I just want to check for the prefix, if it starts with `{'err': True,'e'`, I want to replace the entire string with "". I am not sure of my code, I believe its wrong, that's why I asked a question here

Comment: Maybe this would work: `df.loc[df['output'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict) and x.get('err') == True), 'output'] = ''`

Comment: @IreneHawkins, can you show your expected output ? Also, can you make a reproducible example with the *DataFrame* constructor : `print(df[["output"]].sample(3).to_dict("list"))` ?

Comment: `df.loc[df['output'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict) and x.get('err') == True), 'output'] = ''`

Comment: @Timless, I have added the output for the same,I apologize. My expected output I thought was clear,my bad, I want the values to be replaced with an empty strings, or in other words Nan, I do not want anything to be there.

Comment: @Dogbert, the solution does not work, I still have those cases being retained in the dataframe unfortunately..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have literal strings, so you can simply use [`startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) :

```
df["output"] = df["output"].mask(df["output"].str.startswith("{'err': True, 'e'"))
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  output
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked in an instant, it seems I was stuck on something very trivial, thanks a lot again for your help!